# Можно ли построить JSONObject такого вида

Tags: java, android

Всем привет, помогите вопрос такой можно ли построить строку вида:

```
"interests”:”{“data”:[“1”,”2”,”3”]}”
```

у меня пока получается только так:

```
"interests":{"data":["1","2","3"]}
```

вот код мой

```
 JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
 for (int i = 0; i < interests.size(); i++) {
   array.put(interests.get(i));
 }
 JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
 JSONObject interetsJson =new JSONObject();
 interetsJson.put("data", array);
 jsonParam.put("interests",interetsJson);
 jsonParam.put("sex", sex);
 jsonParam.put("cntPhone", cntPhone);
 jsonParam.put("cntWWW", cntWWW);
 jsonParam.put("bio", bio);
```

Comment: У вас получается на выходе правильная строка *JSON*a на сколько я вижу.

Comment: я вроде понимаю что она правильна, но возможно ли сделать ту которая у меня не получается?

Comment: Возможно. `jsonParam.put("interests",interetsJson.toString());` Но зачем?

Comment: какую вы библиотеку используете?

Comment: Сторонние библиотеки на сколько я понимаю правильность вашего вопроса я не использую.

Comment: fori1ton, спасибо это именно то что я искал. Это нужно было для добавление данных на сервер, по другому не работало.